# How do the virtual clients generated from Jmeter differ from that number of actual clients?

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I am a newbie for Jmeter and now I have assigned a task to test a web page for load and concurrent events.
According to my understanding Jmeter create separate thread for each virtual client and ask them to send request to the web server.But threads are not absolutely concurrent,Do they?
I need to confirm this to check weather one of my web page behave correctly for a absolute concurrent event(Ex : All the clients submit a form at same time with 0 seconds gap)
Does the virtual clients generated from Jmeter behave as same as that number of actual clients when it come to concurrent testing?
If it isn't what can I do to minimize the difference.

Please correct me if I have misunderstood something.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Given you have enough iterations (Loop Count on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level) you should have as many concurrent users as Threads.

If you're looking for sending a request simultaneously, i.e. at exactly the same moment - consider using [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)

Also to make your test more realistic add the following test elements:

- [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
- Configure HTTP Request samplers to download embedded resources and use concurrent thread pool of 2-5 threads for it. You can do it via [HTTP Requests Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configuration element
- [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)

See [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) for more detailed explanation of above recommendations.

Comment: I am already using the "Recording controller" under samplers.Therefore I believe the behavior is same as a real browser.
Thank you for the suggestion about, "Synchronizing Timer".
I set "Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by" to 10(In the thread group there are 10 threads) and timeout to 0.
Following is the result I got for starting time for each thread.
Do you think, this is the best I can get?

16:52:04.097
16:52:04.096
16:52:04.098
16:52:04.097
16:52:04.099
16:52:04.099
16:52:04.095
16:52:04.096
16:52:04.098
16:52:04.097